# What is the apparent magnitude of the faintest stars visible during a full moon?

Tags: the-moon, apparent-magnitude, naked-eye

Assuming the viewer is far from any light pollution, it is a cloudless night, and humidity is very low.  What is the faintest apparent magnitude of stars visible to the naked eye during a full moon (at zenith) if the viewer is looking towards the horizon?

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking about the faintest stars that are visible, rather than the brightest?

Comment: Yup!  Thank you.

Comment: So what you're really asking, I think, is  what's the faintest visible star visible on the horizon at  midnight (sun  opposed) when the moon is not in the field of view.  A nice clean, dry, cold atmosphere means there's almost no scatter from the moon's output into your FOV.

Comment: Would there be no scatter of the moon's output reaching the FOV I'm asking about?  I didn't know whether there would be or not.

Comment: [Related question](/q/10322)

Comment: What do you mean by magnitude?

Comment: @MikeG The link in the answer appears to be dead.

Comment: @InertialIgnorance Magnitude is a unitless measure of the brightness of astronomical objects.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_(astronomy)

Comment: Duplicate https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/10322/around-what-apparent-magnitude-can-the-naked-eye-observe-an-object-during-full-m

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bortle_scale) on the Bortle Scale claims the full moon at a dark site is roughly equivalent to the light pollution at the urban/suburban transition which means you could see stars with an naked-eye limiting magnitude (NELM) 4.6-5.0